# Some modules moving down on my website when I click on the menu? Why?

Tags: css, layout, joomla, web, frontend

I can't manage to understand what's wrong with my website, if it's something with CSS or something else. When I go to the home page http://www.nomadtravellers.com/
the layout is correct. But when clicking on any other menu, as in example "About Us" some of the modules (Photo moasaic, breadcrumbs, etc.) are moving slightly down, while some other are staying in the correct position. Any suggestion on how to fix it?
It is build with joomla 2.5.11 if that matters.
I've already tried to deactivate Css optimization, and it's still the same behaviour

Comment: There's an awful lot of absolute positioning going on in there. Not sure that's the issue...but it's likely.

Comment: It wasn't that, but yes, you are right, the css is not really "clean" but since I'm on my own, I do and learn what I can

Answer (score 1):

you have different styles for main and inner pages. on main page css there's a reset rule for form (the search field form in your header):

```
form {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

on inner pages:

```
form {
   margin-bottom: 18px;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, it was exactly that! Tahnks!!